# Variable in SQL query syntax

Tags: sql, database, variables

I want to make a simple SQL query like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE $variable_2 = $variable_1
```

instead of a default one:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name = $variable_1
```

It seems like first example doesn't work at all. Is it even possible to modify SQL query syntax in such way?

Comment: What database software are you using?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that. It's MySQL

Answer (score 0):

as this reference answer for:
in link:
[Use Variable as SQL column Name in query](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/use-variable-as-sql-column-name-in-query)

answer1:

```
declare @ColumnName varchar(50)

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @ColumnName = 'SalesData_' + convert(varchar(2),datepart(dd,getdate()))

set @sql = 'select ' + @ColumnName + ' from SalesTable'

print @sql

EXEC sp_sqlexec @sql
```

answer 2:

```
declare @ColumnName varchar(50)

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @ColumnName = 'SalesData_' + convert(varchar(2),datepart(dd,getdate()))

set @sql = 'select ' + @ColumnName + ' from yourschema.SalesTable'

print @sql
```